# Is a maximum function concave?

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, convex-analysis

A function such as $$\max (X, Y)$$ given $X\geq 0$, $Y \geq 0$. Because It would form an inverse L shape on the graph, and that looks like a concave function. However my teacher said that the function wasn't quasi concave, so it seems like it can't be concave, I'm a little confused about the behaviour of this function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function $(x,y) \mapsto \mathrm{max}(x,y)$ is *convex* on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: How? I thought when the chord joining any two points on the curve lies below it, the function was concave.

Comment: @dexter You are right, but for this function, the chord lies above the curve. [Here is a plot.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+z%3Dmax%28x%2Cy%29)

Comment: um wow. honestly mind blown, i didnt expect that. Thanks!